# UIRefreshControl conditionally declare for ios 5 and below

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am using `UIRefreshControl` for pull down to refresh for iOS 6, it is working. I am using a custom delegate to update when it is done, in that method I call,

```
[self->refresh endRefreshing];
```

I have declared,

```
UIRefreshControl *refresh;
```

in the interface file, because I am not able to call

```
[self->refresh endRefreshing]
```

from by custom delegate method.

Its all working perfectly for iOS 6, but on lower version of iOS, it fails because `UIRefreshControl' is only available from iOS 6 and above.

How can i conditionally declare them so that it works both on iOS6 and below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare the instance variable as `id`.
2. Cast the variable to `UIRefreshControl *` whenever you use it.
3. Around the places where you are using it, use `if (NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl") != Nil) { ... }` to ensure that `UIRefreshControl` is available.

Comment: Jesper, thank you for the response, i tried it. here is the code i tried with error http://pastebin.com/ZGXXu5Hh

Comment: You have to use the iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: Jasper, Base sdk is set to ios 6, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` with a custom pull to refresh, for example this one: https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/instructure/CKRefreshControl is a drop-in replacement to UIRefreshControl that uses UIRefreshControl on iOS6+, and custom pull-to-refresh logic on previous versions.  I didn't have anything to do with it's development, but it works great!